# Javascript stopping people from seeing api and server keys

Tags: javascript

Is there a way I can stop people from seeing the Javascript Source code that includes the Server API key and server information?

Comment: You need to move the 3rd party request to your backend and create your own API to hide the keys.

Comment: Please see the answers to the linked question [and so many others](/search?q=%5Bjs%5D+hide+source+code).

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not.

You can obfuscate and minify your code, but that doesn't help since your users can look at their browser's Network Inspector instead.